# Get Warning when use component from ant design (React Native)

Tags: react-native, antd

I want to use ant-design component to my react-native project, but I get warning: componentWillReceiveProps will be deprecated.

I check the node_modules, i get this code in folder searchbar:

```
var SearchBar = function (_React$Component) {
// some code
    key: 'componentWillReceiveProps',
    value: function componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if ('value' in nextProps) {
            this.setState({
                value: nextProps.value
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What i must do with this code? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Starting from react 16.8 hookd will replace the previous component lifecycle.
However as stated in the docs:

There are no plans to remove classes from React. You can read more about the gradual adoption strategy for Hooks in the bottom section of this page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `node_modules` manually, but that won't resolve the problem if you ever need to pass the project to a someone and he/she does a fresh install using `npm i`.

You have to either update your project (if the third-party library has been updated) using `npm update 'packageName'` or to ignore the warning adding in your `App.js`:

```
  YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['componentWillReceiveProps']);
```

Note that this will hide all the warnings referring to `componentWillReceiveProps`, and it will only hide them from the emulator/device, leaving them in the console when you are debugging with it.

To update that code, change it to:

```
key: 'componentDidUpdate',
value: function componentDidUpdate() {
  if ('value' in this.props) {
      this.setState({
          value: this.props.value
      });
  }
}
```

If there is another componentDidUpdate in that page, just add it this piece of code